# Nyquist plot- is G(s) stable?

Tags: control-theory

I got very confused with the nyquist plot.
I have a basic question that would suffice:
say I got a general nyquist plot of some transfer function $ G(s) $:

[image]

Is $ G(s) $ stable? what information apart from the evolution of Phase and magnitude I can get from the plot?

I Know that the Nyquist plot gives information about $\frac{1}{1+G(s)} $ stability. But what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nyquist's Theorem is about closed loop stability using open loop frequency response information. If you want to know if the TF $G(s)$ is open loop stable, you do need to work backwards from the phase/mag information to a (crude) bode plot, to a TF in the s-domain. In your Nyquist plot of $G(s),$ we can see the magnitude is approximately constant with an increasing phase of $180^\circ$ for low frequencies. This suggests an unstable pole and stable zero at low frequencies.

As we pass the phase of $180^\circ,$ the magnitude drops rapidly suggesting another pole activates. The phase continues to increase for a brief period. This suggests another unstable pole. The magnitude continues to decrease, but the phase begins to decrease back down to a phase of $90^\circ.$ This suggests an additional two stable poles at high frequencies.

Roughly,

$$G(s) = 0.9\,\frac{\left(\frac{s}{z_1} + 1\right)}{\left(\frac{s}{p_1} + 1\right)\left(\frac{s}{p_2} + 1\right)\left(\frac{s}{p_3} + 1\right)^2},$$

where $z_1 > 0,$ $p_1 \approx -z_1 < 0,$ $p_2 \approx 10\,p_1,$ $p_3 \approx -10\,p_2.$

Example, consider the TF,

$$G(s) = 0.9\,\frac{\left(\frac{s}{1} + 1\right)}{\left(\frac{s}{-1} + 1\right)\left(\frac{s}{-10} + 1\right)\left(\frac{s}{100} + 1\right)^2}.$$

The Nyquist plot of this TF is,

[image]

Pretty close. It isn't perfect, but you get the idea. You can use the real axis intersections to get more precise information. I didn't do that. However, we can see that $G(s)$ is not BIBO stable.

Comment: Another way of arguing of the presence of an unstable pole is that adding a gain between 1/0.6 and 1/0.2 will result in a counterclockwise encirclement of minus one. However, one can't get a negative amount of closed loop unstable poles, so the open loop needs to have at least one unstable pole

Comment: Correction, with those gains you actually get two counterclockwise encirclements, so indeed two unstable open loop poles.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen indeed. I didn't want to show that argument because it implicitly uses the fact that the closed loop is stabilized by a gain between 1/0.6 and 1/0.2. The argument does not work with the Nyquist plot of $G(s) = s/(s^3 - 1)$ or $G(s)=1/((s-1)(s^2 - 1))$ where no gain stabilizes the loop. But, if one knows the closed loop is stable for some gain, then one can deduce the # of unstable poles.

Comment: Indeed. One can't always use that approach of a gain. I believe in your proposed transfer function, one can replace one of the two high frequency with a right half plane zero (since the magnitude would then still go down and the has the same phase contribution as the pole).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, True. With the Nyquist we have a very limited information and it is hard to deduce the slope of the magnitude (or phase, for that matter) from it, which is really what we need to distinguish those cases. Indeed in this case, it might be that the bad zero is appropriate.